# Safari Remembers Previous Sites (Auto-Fill)

Tags: macos, mac, safari

For my privacy I like to reset Safari (Safari menu -> Reset Safari) however it does not clear the auto-fill feature of the Address Bar. How do I clear this?

Comment: You are checking all the boxes, aren't you?

Comment: Mr. Benjamin - I check all the check boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you positive those sites aren't bookmarked? Safari, like Firefox 3, will autocomplete urls that you have bookmarked

Comment: not encountering the same behavior. Using 10.5.8 and Safari 4.0.3. Ensure you are also resetting "Top Sites" also